# Trying to remember crazy java array trickery

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to remember some crazy java array trickery I came over in a certification exam. This was a couple of years ago and I'm a bit fuzzy on the details.

It goes something like this:

```
int[] a = {4,2,1}
int i = a[ a[0] = 0 ]
```

This is of course total bollocks but the question tried to show that an array saves it's state when it's accessed. So if I actually got it right I expected 'i' to equal 4 still, but as shown when run 'i' gets the new value 0.

The certification was for java 6 and I checked thats still what I'm running here (1.6.0_51 to be precise). Is it changed in some way or is my memory just completely off?

Thank you for indulging me in this, in reality, rather meaningless question :)

edit: I would never ever suggest to use or use this sort of weird thing in real code.

Comment: Don't do weird things, you'll have no friends.

Comment: Oh damn it, I was just curious :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

what about official documentaion?
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.13.1

15.13.1 read it =)

Answer (score 3):

```
int i = a[ a[0] = 0 ]
```

is equal to -

```
a[0] = 0 // this assignment change the index 0 value to 0 - {0,2,1}
int i = a[ 0 ] // this 0 comes from assignment operation which is assigned value.
```

so the result is 0.

Comment: where the `0` in the last line is the result of evaluating the previous statement (assignments return the assigned value).

Comment: I do know that would be a more proper way of doing things :) And I rely tried to flesh out this thing so that it would be obvious that the strangeness was intended.